# How can retrieve a specific valued of a UDF field in Candidate Entity

Tags: taleo

For istance, if I have a UDF field with name "test_name" in the Candidate UDF's, I would like to get the value of the UDF with the name "test_name"

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at this this morning, in my case I'm using a C# client generated from the WSDL. I found that there was a property available for all entities called flexValuesField.

This contains an array of UDF values which you can search with your key.